# How to access data set by set() method in Phil Sturgeon CodeIgniter Template?

Tags: codeigniter, templates

I have CI 2.1.3 and Template 1.9

Template 1.9 documentation stated that

> ### set()
>
> Set data using a chainable method. Provide two strings or an array of data.
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> $this->template->set('foo', $bar);
> ```
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> $this->template->build('welcome_message', array('message' => 'Hi there!');
> ```

How can I use that `foo`/`message` variable of above example in view file?

I tried `$template['foo']` and `$foo` in template file, but can't get the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was editing the wrong template file. I can access the variable using

```
 $foo
```

format.